# Google-sheets ARRAYFORMULA and IF conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following two problems:
1. I need to put some value if condition is satisfied for multiple conditions and apply array fourmula on it to auto-update from google forms.
I have typed in in the following code:
=ARRAYFORMULA( IF($B2:$B="","",IF(OR( $B2:$B = "name1" , $B2:$B = "name2") , "value1", IF(OR( $B2:$B =  "name3" , $B2:$B = "name4" , $B2:$B = "name5" ) , "value2")))
and so on for multiple values...
When I use it without ARRAYFORMULA it is working fine, but with it it returns wrong value.
2. I have similar problem to the above but now some of the values can be numbers.
without ARRAYFORMULA it works fine, but with it is not accurate. for example if the answer is 15, it can show me 14.9999999 with the ARRAYFORMULA.

I will be glad for some help for these problems.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OR can't be iterated of an array. Instead, you'd have to use the '+'-sign.
Looking at your formula, I'd suggest another approach. Create a lookup table in a separate tab (maybe call it 'lookuptable') with the names in column A and the values in column B. Then use VLOOKUP on the sheet that receives the form submissions. Something like this:

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(B2:B), iferror(vlookup(B2:B, lookuptable!A2:B, 2, 0)),))
```

Maybe you can apply the same method for your second issue.